# select text from ruby on rails drop-down f.collection_select

Tags: ruby-on-rails, drop-down-menu

I am using a f.collection_select in one of my views and was wondering if it possible to grab the text value of the selected item

edit:
let me be more specific i have 
 <%= f.collection_select(:mealID, @meals, :mealID, :name,{},  { :class => 'btn btn-primary3' })%> i want to grab the :name in the controller to update in my database as meal name plz help

Comment: Yes, it's possible. Are you trying to grab it with Javascript or in your controller?

Comment: trying to grab it with the controller can u possible show me an example?

Answer (score 0):

When you use **<%= f.collection_select(:city_id, City.all, :id, :name) %>**
and submit the form you can get the value in your controller in 
params[:city_id]

Pls check you have used **<%=**

Comment: yes i know this but i want the :name of the city not its :id

Comment: it was just an example you can mention f.collection_select(:name, City.all, :id, :name)

Comment: yes but is there any way of grabing that without switching the :name with :cityid